# Persisting DateTimeOffset to server

Tags: javascript, c#, nancy, datetimeoffset

I'm trying my best to figure out how to persist a datetimeoffset string to the server so that it correctly binds to a DateTimeOffset property.

I've tried using something like this:

```
moment.utc().format() + ' +' +  new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60 + ':00';
```

This was showing as 6/12/2017 22:27 +4:00 and I was sending that to the server as a string but it seems to fail being parsed to a DateTimeOffset object every time.

I'm using Nancy for my web api framework at the moment, but I wonder the same thing for Web API as well.

Currently I'm just sending back the offset and setting the DateTimeOffset property like this:

`dto.CommentDate = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToOffset(new TimeSpan(dto.Offset, 0, 0));`

Is there a better way to do this? Can I send the whole date instead of just the offset?

Comment: How does `new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60` resolve to `+4:00`?

Comment: It's a JavaScript function run on the client, it's also prefixed with ' +'

Comment: You should post the actual code you're using, the example in the OP doesn't do what you say it does. It will return a string like "1497327412934+-10" which is unintelligible to most parsers. If you want to generate an ISO 8601 date and time string with the host offset, then use `moment().format()`, which uses ISO 8601 format by default and returns a string like "2017-06-12T22:27:00+04:00".

Comment: sorry, I've updated it... I ended up changing to to only capture the offset and send that to the server, which is why it was wrong.. ISO 8601 looks like what I want... but that looks just like a datetime format.. would it be possible to get that date as UTC in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: The built-in [*toISOString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring) does that: `new Date().toISOString()` which uses UTC by specification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few things:

- `+04:00` is an offset used in parts of Russia, and a few places in the Middle-East.  From the location mentioned on your blog, I think you meant `-04:00`, which is used for Eastern Daylight Time in the US (among others).  (The JavaScript `getTimezoneOffset` method is inverted with this regard.)
- `+ ':00'` assumes that all time zone offsets are in terms of whole hours.  In reality, many are `:30` and  a few are `:45`.
- In a `DateTimeOffset`, the `DateTime` portion is always the *local time*, not the UTC time.  In other words, the offset is already applied.

  For example, if the local time is `2017-06-16 12:00:00` in the US Eastern time zone, then we'd represent that as `2017-06-16T12:00:00-04:00` (in ISO 8601 format).  The corresponding UTC time would be represented as `2017-06-16T16:00:00Z`.
- Sending the UTC time plus the the local offset is not allowed in ISO 8601 format.  The only format I'm aware of that uses that convention is the older ["ASP.NET JSON Date Format"](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx), that came out of things like `JavaScriptSerializer` class in .NET.  The corresponding value to the previous example would be `/Date(1497628800000-0400)/`.  As you can see, the timestamp portion is a millisecond-resolution version of Unix Time, which is UTC based.  The offset has not been applied, and is thus extraneous.  This format considered deprecated now, so please don't do this.
- You appear to be using moment.js on the client side.  This can easily generate the string you need to send.

  ```
  // get the current time, as an ISO 8601 string, with whole-second resolution
  moment().format()  // "2017-06-16T12:00:00-04:00"

  // or, with millisecond resolution
  moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSSZ')  // "2017-06-16T12:00:00.000-04:00"
  ```
- On the server side, just expose your property as a `DateTimeOffset`.  Don't try to construct it yourself.